# Redirect from one directory to a subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all the urls of a directory (example.com/blog/urlnames) on one domain to a sub-domain (blog.example.com/urlnames)

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/blog$ [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) https://blog.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I keep getting a 404 error when I type the url on example.com:
`https://example.com/blog/5-names-for-actors/`

I want this to go to:
`https://blog.example.com/5-names-for-actors/`

Comment: `/blog` is not a valid host name, that RewriteCond will never match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://blog.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

File `blog/.htaccess` may not be existing already so you may have to create it.

Comment: It's working, but, it's redirecting me to the sub-domain even if I just type example.com and nothing else. I did put the .htaccess in the /blog directory. Can it work so that only if visitors type /blog/5-names-for-actors/ then it directs. But, if a visitor types example.com, it goes to the index file?

Comment: If it is placed in `blog/` directory then it won't affect `http://example.com/`. Make sure you test it after clearing browser cache or test from a new browser.